# Events not honored on text inputs or textarea elements within iframe on ipad ios 5

Tags: javascript, ipad, events, ios5, textarea

I have a form within an iframe on a website that I am testing on iPad. It seems that the touch events do not work on the inputs with type "text" or textarea elements. Swiping or touching does nothing on those areas and the keyboard does not pop up. The combo box (select) elements I can interact with just fine. Is anyone else having this problem?

I have no issues on iPad iOS 4.3 only on iPad iOS 5.  The markup and styling are pretty standard, but if no one else is experiencing this issue I can post the code. The only unique element that I can think of is that all of the markup is loaded dynamically using jQuery tmpl.

I have only seen documentation online regarding scrolling of textareas but this seems to be a separate issue.

Correction ***

I just hit the page directly (outside of the iframe) and am still having the same problem. So has anyone seen this behavior before? Is it due to strange CSS styling? Z-indexing?

Answer (score 2):

OKAY GOT IT! So I noticed that click events were registering but default drag behavior was not. I also remembered that I had implemented a jquery ui extension for draggable behavior that hooked touch events into their click and mousemove event handling. That was the culprit. I removed that extension and added this instead : github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch This works on both iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I guess that has to be a bug in iOS...

Or could you post a link to what you have made?
I could test it on my iPod Touch...

Comment: thanks for trying... can't post the source, but I have tried ripping just the markup out and it works fine. I then ripped out all css from the original webapp.... still broken... must be javascript but I have also deleted all my event handlers (i think)...  if I can isolate some code that duplicates it but is not my client's source I will post it.

Comment: Well, I tried all kinds of things... I saw no js errors. Click events are registering on the textarea and input type="text" elements so I just added $('textarea, input').click(function(){$(this).focus()}); and that brought the keyboard up on touch... however there is still a deadzone on my page where dragging is being thwarted. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem for days now, and from googling around, most of the internet has too.  But none of the posts contained an answer. This is the solution that worked for me. It's based on   https://gist.github.com/tamarasaurus/dcf2d0331043586421f3.  Hopefully this will help people in the future, or at least point them in the right direction.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    window.focus();
});

document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    window.focus();
});
```